# Definition of brackets in index notation

Tags: tensors

I've come across the notation $B_{[ij]}$ and $\partial_{[k}B_{ij]}$.  What do these notations mean?

The text says that $[ij] := (ij-ij)/2$, but doesn't the $ij$ just specify the which component of the tensor $B$ that we're discussing?  I don't see how you can do math on the indices like that.  The second notation with the brackets on both the derivative operator and $B$ looks even more confusing.

Comment: I think the intention is that $B_{[ij]}$ means $\frac{B_{ij} - B_{ji}}{2}$. Not sure about the second thing but it's probably also some antisymmetrization.

Comment: Oh.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: You have a mistake in the indices in your post, it should read $(ij-ji)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is that

$$B_{[ij]}=\frac 12 \left(B_{ij}-B_{ji}\right)$$

and

$$\partial_{[k}B_{ij]}=\frac 16 \left(\partial_{k}B_{ij}+\partial_{i}B_{jk}+\partial_{j}B_{ki}-\partial_{k}B_{ji}-\partial_{j}B_{ik}-\partial_{i}B_{kj}\right).$$